# Very fast movement of a node upon contact

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

In my scenario using Veins-4a2 I am interested to calculate the distance between two nodes (in my scenario nodes are bikes) during a contact. I got the coordinates of the two nodes and I calculated the distance between them.

I noticed that the source node moves very fast during a contact. For example:

at t= 55.104470531278 s ,the source node (434.32;282.398;1.895) sends data to the receiver node (448.664;307.657;1.895).

at t= 55.104753531277 s ,the same source node (**438.981;284.728**;1.895) sends data to the same receiver node (448.664;307.657;1.895).

So the source node, in 0.283 ms, moves up to 5 meters. This behaviour is anormal and illogical. I need help to understand this behaviour please.

Comment: Does this happen on a junction?

Comment: How can I verify please, during a contact, if there is a junction ?

Comment: Is the SUMO network you are simulating publicly available? Did you create it yourself?

Comment: I created the SUMO network by myself using these typemaps: osmNetconvert.typ.xml , osmNetconvertUrbanDe and osmNetconvertBicycle.

Comment: You might have turned off generation of *internal lanes* (that is, lanes in junctions). If this feature is turned off, vehicles will simply "jump" over the junction.

Comment: Thank you for this idea, I will verify it.